# Only last input data is showing in the lists, Whenever I input the new value in the form, the new data is updated but prev one is updated too

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Only last input data is showing in the lists, Whenever I input the new value in the form, the new data is updated but previous one is updated too.
This is how the output is showing in the lists:[image]

here is the code of the file **model.dart**:

```
class Model {
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName = "";
  String email = "";
  String password = "";


  Model({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.password});
}
```

and here is my main file on which I am inserting the data into form, and showing the output in the lists on the same screen:

```
class DialogForm extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Model> models = <Model>[];
  Model tempModel = Model();
  final newModel = Model();

  DialogForm();

  @override
  State<DialogForm> createState() => _ResultState();
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<Model>('model', tempModel));
  }
}

class _ResultState extends State<DialogForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Successful')),

      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.models.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.models[index].firstName),
                    subtitle: Text(widget.models[index].lastName),
                    trailing: Text(widget.models[index].email),
                  )
                )
                )

              ),


            Align(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Click Me!'),
                  onPressed: (){
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Stack(
                          overflow: Overflow.visible,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              right: -40,
                              top: -40,
                              child: InkResponse(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Form(
                                key: _formKey,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'First Name',
                                        validator: (String value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Enter your first name';
                                          }
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          widget.tempModel.firstName = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'Last Name',
                                        validator: (String value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Enter your last name';
                                          }
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          print(value);
                                          widget.tempModel.lastName = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'Enter email',
                                        isEmail: true,
                                        // validator: (String value) {
                                        //   if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                                        //     return 'Please enter a valid email';
                                        //   }
                                        //   return null;
                                        // },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          widget.tempModel.email = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: RaisedButton(
                                        child: Text("Submit"),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // var m = widget.tempModel;
                                          // print(m.firstName + "" + m.lastName + "" + m.email);
                                          // return;
                                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                                            //  var m = widget.tempModel;
                                            // print(m.firstName + "" + m.lastName + "" + m.email);
                                            widget.models.add(widget.tempModel);
                                            setState(() {
                                              widget.models = widget.models;
                                              // widget.tempModel.add(new widget.models());
                                            }
                                            );
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                );
              }

              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;

  MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe you should move the following variables:

```
 List<Model> models = <Model>[];
  Model tempModel = Model();
  final newModel = Model();
```

into the state class because it makes more sense for them to be there, with the exception maybe of `newModel`, but I will address `newModel` in a second.

You **never** use `newModel`. **ever** why not get rid of it???

Ok, now, you could make a factory constructor for your model like this:

```
class Model {
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName = "";
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  Model({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.password});

  factory Model.fromModel(Model model) {
    return Model(firstName: model.firstName, lastName: model.lastName, email: model.email, password: model.password);
  }
}
```

and when adding a new model:

```
models.add(Model.fromModel(tempModel));
```

Hopefully, these changes can solve your issue

### EDIT

To remove an item from the list, you could do something similar to this:

```
ListTile(
  title: Row(
    children: [
      TextButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: () {
          models.removeAt(index);
          setState(() => models = models):
        },
      Text(models[index].firstName),
    ]
  ),
  subtitle: Text(models[index].lastName),
  trailing: Text(models[index].email),
)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank You So Much!. One Question, why we used factory constructor in the model, because I have barely seen any model class with factory constructor in tutorials.

Comment: Happy to help, factory constructors work similar to normal constructors except instead of making a new instance, they return it, using one here makes in my opinion the most sense, but it is by no means a necessity, here is how you would do the same with a normal non-factory constructor: `Model.fromModel(Model model): firstName = model.firstName, lastName = model.lastName, email = model.email, password = model.password;` I just prefer the factory syntax

Comment: Also, sorry to ask, but if my answer solved the issue, would you mind marking it as an accepted answer so I get som reputation?

Comment: I did upvote, but it is showing **Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded**.

Comment: and I now I want to do another thing, adding delete and edit functionalities on each **ListTile**, what I should be doing?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to remove items, and regarding marking an answer as accepted, would you mind taking a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: glad I helped you :)